# In case of a given graph , Is that possible to build trapezoidal map in linear time

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry

[This regarding to Computational geometry in CS]

Let's say that I have a graph G which contains v vectices and e edges, For instance a veronoi diagram VD(G).

I'd like to build a [trapezodial map](http://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/CG12/lecture/Chapter%209.pdf) out of my given graph,

Is that possible to build trapezodial map in linear time for a given graph, Instead of O(nlogn) regular construction time ?

I have been thinking about sweep line trapezoidal map construction where for each edge during the sweep line would construct the upper and lower sites.

Thanks in advanced